# pip install ignoring child directories on install with django project

Tags: python, django, pip

I am writing a Django application and am very new to the framework and python.  I am following the tutorial here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/intro/reusable-apps/ and am currently at packaging and installing the application created from this tutorial: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/intro/tutorial01/

This is my first Django application and my first time using Python.

Currently my setup.py file looks like this:

```
import os
from setuptools import find_packages, setup

with open(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'README.rst')) as readme:
    README = readme.read()

# allow setup.py to be run from any path
os.chdir(os.path.normpath(os.path.join(os.path.abspath(__file__), os.pardir)))

setup(
    name= 'django-polls',
    version='0.1',
    packages=find_packages(),
    include_package_date=True,
    license='BSD License', #example license
    description = 'A simple Django app to conduct Web-based polls.',
    long_description = README,
    url='https://www.example.com',
    author='Your Name',
    author_email='yourname@example.com',
    classifiers=[
        'Environment :: Web Environment',
        'Framework :: Django',
        'Framework :: Django :: 1.9.6',  # replace "X.Y" as appropriate
        'Intended Audience :: Developers',
        'License :: OSI Approved :: BSD License',  # example license
        'Operating System :: OS Independent',
        'Programming Language :: Python',
        # Replace these appropriately if you are stuck on Python 2.
        'Programming Language :: Python :: 3',
        'Programming Language :: Python :: 3.4',
        'Programming Language :: Python :: 3.5',
        'Topic :: Internet :: WWW/HTTP',
        'Topic :: Internet :: WWW/HTTP :: Dynamic Content',
    ],
)
```

my MANIFEST.in file looks like this:

```
include LICENSE
include README.rst
recursive-include polls/static *
recursive-include polls/templates *
recursive-include docs *
```

my file directory is as follows:

```
|polls
  |__init.py__
  |admin.py
  |apps.py
  |models.py
  |tests.py
  |urls.py
  |views.py
  |__pychache__
    |# pycachestuff
  |migrations
    |# migrations stuff
  |static
    |polls
      |images
        |background.gif
      |style.css
  |templates
    |polls
       |detail.html
       |index.html
       |results.html
  |docs
    |
```

When I run the setup, the produced .zip works great, all the directories are included.  However, when I run

```
pip install C:\Path\To\dist\django-polls-0.1.zip -t C:\Path\To\Package
```

It *only* installs what is immediately under the primary polls directory and migrations.  It ignores the subdirectories static and templates.  It also ignores docs, but the folder is empty and the tutorial has led me to believe empty directories are ignored.

Does anyone know how I can fix this?  A few answers I have seen suggest using package_data or data_files, but I'm very new to python and I can't seem to get the syntax right (or those answers are wrong).

Thank you for your time